# C pointer assignment inside a function

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to assign a pointer to an array element inside the function `get_by_id`.

The function get_by_id finds the element correctly and assigns to element to lp, however when it comes back to the caller (`set_attr`), it reverts to `NULL`.

I'm not understanding why it's reverting to `NULL` in the caller, let alone how to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char name[128];
    int attr;
} Lookup;


static int num_sources = 0;

Lookup ltable[128];


void add(int id, const char *name)
{
    sprintf(ltable[num_sources].name, name);
    ltable[num_sources].id = id;
    ltable[num_sources].attr = 999;  // example default attr 999
    num_sources++; // increment the number of sources
}


int get_by_id(int id, Lookup *lp)
{
    int status = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        lp = &ltable[i];
        if (id == lp->id)
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}


int set_attr(const int id, const int attr)
{
    Lookup *lp = NULL;
    int status = get_by_id(id, lp);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        lp->attr = attr;
    }
    return status;
}

int main(void) {
    add(88, "main"); // example id 88
    set_attr(88, 9); // example attr 9
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: C is pass by value. Pass its address.

Comment: " how to fix it."  Do you expect `lp` in `set_attr()` to remain unchanged if a matching `id` not found?

Comment: I don't, I expect status to remain == 1 and check that from the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the value of `lp` you must use a double pointer:

```
int get_by_id(int id, Lookup **lp)
{
    int status = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        *lp = &ltable[i];
        if (id == (*lp)->id)
        {
            status = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

and call like:

```
    int status = get_by_id(id, &lp);
```

Because C is "pass by value", a copy of `lp` is made and passed to the function. Any change to that copy cannot be seen by the caller. To allow the called function to change the variable of the caller, you pass the address of the caller's variable, so the called function can change it. In your case, you pass the *address* of `lp` written as `&lp`.

---

The following version may be peferred:

```
#define T_SIZE (sizeof(ltable)/sizeof(ltable[0]))

Lookup *get_by_id(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T_SIZE; i++)
        if (id == ltable[i].id)
            return &ltable[i];

    return 0;
}
```

Note that it returns a pointer to the table entry and zero if not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just pass the `Lookup` parameter by reference rather by value.
This is because you can only modify the `parameter` only if it is passed by reference.

```
int get_by_id(int id, Lookup *lp)
{
    int status = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        *lp = ltable[i];
        if (id == lp->id)
        {
            status = 0;
            printf("lp=%X\n", lp);
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

int set_attr(const int id, const int attr)
{
    Lookup lp = {0};
    int status = get_by_id(id, &lp);
    if (status == 0)
    {
        printf("lp = %X\n", &lp);
        lp.attr = attr;
    }
    return status;
}
```

This should work.